# Geometric interpretation of $x_1^2y_1^2+x_2^2y_2^2+x_3^2y_3^2+\dots$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, inner-products

Say $x$ and $y$ are two $L_2$ unit vectors of size $n$. In that case the inner product:

$$x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+\dots+x_ny_n$$

Is the cosine of the angle between them.

For an application I was originally interested in the angle like this, but I have only been able to achieve the squared inner product:

$$x_1^2y_1^2+x_2^2y_2^2+x_3^2y_3^2+\dots+x_n^2y_n^2$$

And now I wonder if this has any interesting geometrical interpretations? I suppose it can't be too closely related to the angle between the vectors, given the value can only be in the interval $[0,1]$.

I suppose this is also similar to what we have in the Cauchy Schartz inequality, after some rewriting, but I'm not sure what the geometric intepretation is of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your function is dependent on your choice of orthonormal basis. One can rotate the two vectors and get a different answer.

Comment: That's a really interesting observation. I suppose that means hints there are not actually any geometrical interpretations?